# NPM error message when trying to install Parcel

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

[image: This is the Error while installing the package parcel]

I've tried a few solutions found online, but none seem to work. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Tarun\Desktop\NamasteReact\node_modules\lmdb
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp-build-optional-packages
npm ERR! C:\Users\Tarun\Desktop\NamasteReact\node_modules\node-gyp-build-optional-packages\index.js:77
npm ERR!   throw new Error('No native build was found for ' + target + '\n    attempted loading from: ' + dir + ' and package:' +   
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! 
...
```

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

there maybe multiple reasons why this is happening,
you can try few of the solutions and let me know wether they worked or not.

```
    1.) npm install --global npm@latest
    2.) npm cache clean --force
    3.) npm install --global windows-build-tools
    4.) try install parcel with help of yarn
    5.) also check your python version, and if it is not updated then install LTS or latest version
```

Comment: getting same error again.